# Microsoft Azure Custom Translator Service models are forever on "training queued"

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I am trying to test the custom translations API provided by Azure. I created a workspace > created a project > uploaded two txt files (source in english and target in target language) > selected the successfully uploaded txt files and clicked "Create Model". For almost 2 days now, the status has been "training queued". I'm wondering if there's a standard waiting time for training to finish or if something has gone wrong? I've created one model with just 4 sentences in each txt file to train and another one with just 1 sentence even to see if that would speed up training. Both are still "training queued". Am I supposed to let my machine stay awake during the entire training process (I assume no but whatever is the case my machine was at the very least awake for several hours while the custom translator portal was open to the page where my "training queued" models were)? Does it typically take x business days to train a model regardless of the training data size?
[Custom Translator Portal][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyfex.png

Comment: This is too long for training. Your computer does not need to stay on after you queue the training. please email custommt@microsoft.com with your workspace and project details, and we can investigate

Comment: Thank you! @Fai